# Input string was not in a correct format. Can't tell where's the problem

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to make a program to check if values are even or odd. And I want it to show a line of text if the user doesn't input an integer. I'm doing this with an if statement and the tryparse method.
Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, insert a number");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int Num = Convert.ToInt32(input);
if ( ! int.TryParse(input, out Num))
{
    Console.Write("That's not even a number...");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is the number odd?");
    int remainder = Num % 2;
    Console.WriteLine(remainder != 0);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Is the number even?");
    Console.WriteLine(remainder == 0);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: What did you type in the console? What is the value of `input`?

Comment: Why are you running `Convert.ToInt32(input)` _and_ `int.TryParse(input, out Num)`?

Comment: Remove the line `Convert.ToInt32(input)` like @gunr2171 suggests and the program should continue evaluating the `if`.

Comment: And make it a habbit to have local variable name start with a lowercase. Not `Num` but `num`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

`int Num = Convert.ToInt32(input);`

This is trying to convert the input to an integer *before* checking if it can actually be parsed as an int. If you send `a` into `Convert.ToInt32()` it will fail because `a` is not an int.

Remove this line, add the variable declaration in the next line (`int.TryParse(input, out int Num)`), and your code should work like you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, but nit pick, you can't remove the entire line. The variable declaration still needs to be there, or remove the entire line _and_ put the declaration in the parameter of `TryParse`.

Comment: Good nit pick :) You're absolutely right, of course. Disadvantage of using my brain as a compiler instead of actually writing out code on the computer. `int.TryParse(input, out int Num)` should solve it.